# Pandas : Chaning date to a format where I can use `map`

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to get current data in string format `(Month-Date-Year)`

`def user_defined_function(date_str):` I have a user defined function which takes input date(`refresh_date`) in the above mentioned format. So I need to change the today's date to the required format and map it.

What I Tried :

```
   import datetime as dt
   from datetime import date
   refresh_date=date.today().strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
   x=refresh_date.map(user_defined_function).values[0]
```

I am however getting an error using the above code `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'map'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Series with your `refresh_date` variable:

```
refresh_date = pd.Series([date.today().strftime('%m-%d-%Y')])
x = refresh_date.map(user_defined_function).values[0]
```

Comment: `refresh_date = pd.Series([date.today().strftime('%m-%d-%Y')])
x=refresh_date.map(user_defined_function).values[0]` : this worked for me as well